# UPDATE to subtract downtime per hour

Tags: sql, postgresql, datetime, sql-update

I have 2 tables.

The `dummy` table:

[image: dummy table]

and the `down_event` table:

[image: down_event table]

`availability_time` in the `dummy` table ranges from 00:00:00 to 23:00:00. Every `down_duration_sec` in the `down_event` table shall be subtracted from `duration_sec` in the corresponding row of the `dummy` table. An event occurring at `down_time` 03:59:59 only applies to the row with `availability_time` 03:00:00 in the `dummy` table.

The example above only shows rows for 2020-02-25, but there can be many dates for the same `terminal_id`.

To be clear, assuming these rows in table `dummy`:

```
terminal_id    availability_date   availability_time   duration_sec
___________    _________________   _________________   ____________
02262261       2020-02-25          00:00:00            3600
02262261       2020-02-25          01:00:00            3600
02262261       2020-02-25          02:00:00            3600
02262261       2020-02-25          03:00:00            3600
```

For an event occurring on the date 2020-02-25 at the time 1:43:23 with a `down_duration_sec` of 10 seconds, the `dummy` table shall be updated to:

```
terminal_id    availability_date   availability_time   duration_sec
___________    _________________   _________________   ____________
02262261       2020-02-25          00:00:00            3600
02262261       2020-02-25          01:00:00            3590
02262261       2020-02-25          02:00:00            3600
02262261       2020-02-25          03:00:00            3600
```

So far this is my query code:

```
    UPDATE dashboard.dummy 
SET duration_sec = 3600 - t.down_duration_sec
FROM (  
    SELECT down_duration_sec
    FROM dashboard.down_event 
    WHERE terminal_id IN (SELECT terminal_id FROM dashboard.dummy)
    GROUP BY down_duration_sec
) t 
WHERE t.terminal_id = dashboard.dummy.terminal_id
AND availability_date IN (
    SELECT down_date 
    FROM dashboard.down_event 
    WHERE down_date IN ( SELECT availability_date FROM dashboard.dummy)
)
```

This query works and was able to populate the terminal_id, availability_date and availability_time.

But once I add this code to subtract the `duration_sec`:

```
AND availability_time IN(
    SELECT terminal_id, down_time
    FROM dashboard.down_event 
    WHERE down_time between
    (
        SELECT terminal_id, availability_time 
        FROM dashboard.dummy 
        WHERE terminal_id IN (SELECT terminal_id FROM dashboard.down_event)
        GROUP BY terminal_id, availability_time
    ) 
    AND
    (
        SELECT availability_time + interval '1 hour'
        FROM dashboard.dummy
        WHERE terminal_id IN (SELECT terminal_id FROM dashboard.down_event)
        GROUP BY availability_time
    )
)
```

.. I get the error:

> subquery must return only one column

How do I get the subtraction right?

Comment: This can't work since you're returning 2 columns. `AND availability_time IN (SELECT terminal_id, down_time`. Might work better with JOINs, I'd have to set this up locally and dig in.

Comment: I took the liberty to clarify as best as I understood after reading the question a couple of times. Please adjust if I didn't get it right. Note that plain text is very much preferred over images, and always declare your version of Postgres.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming all columns to be `NOT NULL`.

```
UPDATE dashboard.dummy d
SET    duration_sec = 3600 - t.sum_down
FROM  (
   SELECT terminal_id, down_date, date_trunc('hour', down_time) AS down_time
        , sum(down_duration_sec) AS sum_down
   FROM   dashboard.down_event 
   GROUP  BY 1, 2, 3
   ) t
WHERE  (t.terminal_id, t.down_date        , t.down_time)
     = (d.terminal_id, d.availability_date, d.availability_time)
```

In subquery `t`, aggregate multiple downtimes per hour (if that's possible?) after truncating to the hour with [`date_trunc()`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-datetime.html#FUNCTIONS-DATETIME-TRUNC). Then join to it in a `FROM` clause. This only updates rows in the `dummy` table that actually *need* an update (should be very few) - as opposed to the subselect demonstrated by George, which updates *every* row (lots of empty updates). Massively cheaper. See:

- [How do I (or can I) SELECT DISTINCT on multiple columns?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54418/how-do-i-or-can-i-select-distinct-on-multiple-columns/12632129#12632129)

The expression `date_trunc('hour', down_time)` produces an `interval`, but the comparison to `time` still works.

Aside: seems odd to subtract downtime from the starting hour instead of actually affected hours.

Answer (score 0):

The most straightforward way to do this is with a subselect in the update statement, e.g.:

```
update dummy d set duration_sec = coalesce( 
  (select 3600 - sum(de.down_duration_sec)
   from down_event de
   where date_trunc('hour', de.down_date + de.down_time) = date_trunc('hour',d.availability_date + d.availability_time)
    and d.terminal_id = de.terminal_id
 ),3600) ;
```

Answer (score 0):

Thank you all for answering.

I fixed this problem by using this query:

```
UPDATE dashboard.dummy 
SET duration_sec = 3600 - t.down_duration_sec
FROM (  
    SELECT down_duration_sec, down_date, terminal_id, down_time
    FROM dashboard.down_event 
    WHERE terminal_id IN (SELECT terminal_id FROM dashboard.dummy)
    GROUP BY down_duration_sec, down_date, terminal_id, down_time
) t 
WHERE t.terminal_id = dashboard.dummy.terminal_id
AND dashboard.dummy.availability_date = t.down_date
AND t.down_time BETWEEN dashboard.dummy.availability_time AND dashboard.dummy.availability_time + interval '1 hour'
```

I just used the `BETWEEN AND` of the query.

Comment: `GROUP BY down_duration_sec, down_date, terminal_id, down_time` seems like noise? (Unless there can be complete duplicates and you only want to use each set once?) OTOH, can you rule out multiple *distinct* downtimes for the same hour? If that can happen, this query breaks because you cannot update the same row multiple times in the same `UPDATE`. Plus, `BETWEEN` is corner-case wrong the way you have it, since it *includes* lower and upper bound, while you want to *exclude* the start of the next hour.